# SAS: tabulate with a row for every metric*class combination

Tags: sas

I'm trying to run a `PROC TABULATE` to get means for various variables split across a class variable (called `brand`). I'd like the output to come out so that it's **one row for each combination of metric & `brand`**. This is so I can copy the output into Excel and create a pivot table to share with users. The table would be 1 column X however many rows `brand*metric` generates.

The problem is that SAS will generate nested cells with merged tables, so I can't easily copy and paste the output -- I'd have to manually clean a bunch of cells.

I'm not very knowledgeable in SAS, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show an example. What is "metric"? Do you mean your analysis variable that you want generate the MEAN of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use `PROC UNIVARIATE`, if I understand what you want. Let's use SASHELP.CARS as our example data.  We can treat MODEL as your BRAND and get the mean of the MPG variables.

```
proc univariate noprint
  data=sashelp.cars(where=(make=:'H'))
  outtable=stats (keep=make _var_ _label_ _mean_)
;
  class  make ;
  var mpg: ;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs     Make         _VAR_          _LABEL_        _MEAN_
 1     Honda      MPG_City       MPG (City)       27.8235
 2     Hummer     MPG_City       MPG (City)       10.0000
 3     Hyundai    MPG_City       MPG (City)       23.0000
 4     Honda      MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    34.0000
 5     Hummer     MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    12.0000
 6     Hyundai    MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    29.9167
```

**Note: PROC UNIVARIATE will not allow more than two class variables. If you have more than two class variables you can just sort the source data and use a `BY` statement instead of the `CLASS` statement.**

If you need multiple combinations of class variables (MAKE MAKE*DRIVETRAIN etc) then you probably want to use PROC SUMMARY instead.  But you will then need to transpose the data set to convert the variables into rows instead of columns.  Plus PROC SUMMARY has many fewer statistics available in this simple output format than are available in the OUTTABLE= results from PROC UNIVARIATE.

```
%let class_list=make drivetrain ;
%let class_types=() make make*drivetrain ;
%let varlist = mpg: ;

proc summary chartype
  data=sashelp.cars(where=(make=:'H'))
;
  class &class_list ;
  types &class_types ;
  var &varlist ;
  output out=stats(where=(_stat_='MEAN')) ;
run;
proc transpose data=stats out=want;
  by _type_ &class_list ;
  var &varlist ;
  id _stat_;
run;
proc print; run;
```

Result

```
                            Drive
Obs    _TYPE_     Make      Train      _NAME_          _LABEL_         MEAN

  1      00                          MPG_City       MPG (City)       25.3000
  2      00                          MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    31.6333
  3      10      Honda               MPG_City       MPG (City)       27.8235
  4      10      Honda               MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    34.0000
  5      10      Hummer              MPG_City       MPG (City)       10.0000
  6      10      Hummer              MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    12.0000
  7      10      Hyundai             MPG_City       MPG (City)       23.0000
  8      10      Hyundai             MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    29.9167
  9      11      Honda      All      MPG_City       MPG (City)       19.6667
 10      11      Honda      All      MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    23.6667
 11      11      Honda      Front    MPG_City       MPG (City)       30.3077
 12      11      Honda      Front    MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    37.0769
 13      11      Honda      Rear     MPG_City       MPG (City)       20.0000
 14      11      Honda      Rear     MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    25.0000
 15      11      Hummer     All      MPG_City       MPG (City)       10.0000
 16      11      Hummer     All      MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    12.0000
 17      11      Hyundai    Front    MPG_City       MPG (City)       23.0000
 18      11      Hyundai    Front    MPG_Highway    MPG (Highway)    29.9167
```

Comment: This actually works really well! How would I do combination of classes? For example, let's say I wanted to combine `make` and `driveTrain` to see the results. Would I still be able to see an overall level for `make`?

Comment: Also what do you do if you need more than 2 class variables? Seems SAS has a limit.

Comment: If you need multiple combinations of class variables then you would need to call it multiple times.  At that point you probably would want to use proc summary instead.

Comment: When I try 3 class variables I get this error: 
ERROR: Cannot specify more than two CLASS variables.

Comment: How would I go about keeping the `n` and `standard error of the mean`? I tried playing with this but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Read the manual. Run PROC CONTENTS on the generated OUTTABLE dataset.  Adjust or remove the KEEP= option.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use `ods output` to get this into a table, then use `proc transpose` to make it how you want it.  `PROC TABULATE` is going to make something that looks nice, not necessarily something useful for your specific purpose.

```
ods output table=tab_out;
proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars;
  class make;
  var mpg_city mpg_highway;
  tables make*(mpg_city mpg_highway),mean;
run;
ods output close;

proc transpose data=tab_out out=tab_trans;
  by make;
  var mpg_:;
run;
```

With `PROC MEANS` it can skip the transpose if you are 9.3+ and have `STACKODSOUTPUT` option available to you; without that (in older versions) just remove that option and then do the transpose:

```
ods output summary=means_out;
proc means data=sashelp.cars mean stackodsoutput;
  class make;
  var mpg_city mpg_highway;
run;
ods output close;
```

Comment: What if I just used proc means? I'm fine with doing that. Is there a workflow to use proc means and then transpose everything?

Comment: `tabulate` seems just as easy in this case?  Sure, `proc means` would give nearly the same result.

Comment: Done.  Actually slightly easier in 9.3+ with `STACKODSOUTPUT`.

Comment: I tried both of your solutions and the problem remains -- the `Make` cells are merged, so when I copy this to Excel I get the same problem.

Comment: Don't use the on-screen output.  Use the dataset that is produced, then print it or export it or what have you.

Comment: Got it. How do I alter the transpose command if I run proc means?

Comment: If you do it the way I show above, you don't use it at all.  If you don't have STACKODSOUTPUT available, I would imagine it should work just as is (just with different named dataset if you name it differently).

Comment: WARNING: No variables found beginning with 'MPG_' in data set WORK.CARS_OUT.

Comment: If you use `STACKODSOUTPUT` then you would not do that transpose step.  If you didn't, then there should be some variables beginning with MPG_.